# Correct argument list syntax for className and css modules using BEM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, css-modules

I am using React and a very simple CSS modules setup with webpack. Also using BEM for class names.

Classnames with dashes are not valid unless in string form, and I have not yet found a string version that does not repeatedly reference the css import statement for each class entry.

Both of these are not ideal and I would like to avoid using a library.

```
<div className={classNames({[styles.foo]: true, [styles.bar]: true})}>
<div className={[styles.foo, styles.bar].join(' ')}>
```

These do not work

```
className={styles['one two']}
className={styles['one', 'two']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use template literals:

```
className={`${styles.foo} ${styles.bar}`}
```

although I advice the use of [classNames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames), as it really comes in handy to add conditional class names. You can also use the binded approach

```
var cx = classNames.bind(styles);
className={cx('foo', 'bar')}
```

Comment: template literals do not work with BEM. However the library classNames does appear to be the best choice as a pairing with vanilla CSS es6-modules